# "Unexpected token import" error while running test cases using jest

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs

```
 import('react-ace').then(function (component) {
      ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

  22 |   />
  23 | );
> 24 | ButtonList.defaultProps = {
  25 |   text: '',
  26 |   primary: false,
  27 |   onclick: null,

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:316:17)
```

The above error occurs when i run test cases using jest. 
I am using react, webpack and jest.

Comment: can you share your package.json and babelrc ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not config babel properly.
I can help if you post "package.json" and ".babelrc"
**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

OR

Install `babel-jest` package.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer, it should be a comment.